# Z-Index not working with IE8 even though the menu has a higher value

Tags: css, z-index

All,
If you look at the following webpage:

http://tinyurl.com/7a5htbt

If you scroll over the view recipes in IE8 it goes behind the scrolling images. I'm not sure why because the images have a z-index of 2 and the menu drop down has a z-index of 999. Any idea why this isn't working?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in IE, positioned elements start a new stacking order, causing what you are seeing. Sometimes you can give the parent element a higher z-index and it will solve the issue. Google for IE z-index bug and you'll find a fair amount of text on the subject.